# How to restrict queue deletion or purging in ActiveMQ 5.11.0?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am wondering how could we restrict users from deleting a queue in Activemq. I am using simpleAuthenticationPlugin and authorizationPlugin for configuring user and access management.

```
<destinations>              
        <queue physicalName="QUEUEA" />
        <queue physicalName="QUEUEB" />
</destinations>

<plugins>
       <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
           <users>  
                <authenticationUser username="admin"    password="admin" groups="admins"/>
                <authenticationUser username="user1"    password="pwd1" groups="user1group"/>   
                <authenticationUser username="user2" password="pwd2" groups="user2group"/>                  
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
<authorizationPlugin>
            <map>
                <authorizationMap>
                    <authorizationEntries>                          
                            <authorizationEntry queue = "QUEUEA.>" read="user1group" write="user1group" admin="admins"/>
                            <authorizationEntry queue = "QUEUEB.>" read="user2group" write="user2group" admin="admins"/>
                            <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
                            <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="user2group,user1group" write="user2group,user1group" admin="admins,user2group,user1group" />
                    </authorizationEntries>
                </authorizationMap>
            </map>
        </authorizationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

I am looking for a configuration which stops users to delete and purge any queue. Sample code which I am using to delete a queue:

```
public static void deleteDestinationQueue(String username, String password, String destName) throws JMSException{       
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
    ActiveMQConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection(username,password);
        ActiveMQDestination destination = ActiveMQDestination.createDestination(destName, ActiveMQDestination.QUEUE_TYPE);  
        connection.destroyDestination(destination);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        connection.close();
    }       
}
```

Comment: I quickly set up a 5.14 instance of AMQ and have the same configuration on my active mq conf. When i run the same code i get permission errors.             Version : Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 , javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User user1 is not authorized to remove: queue://QUEUEA.TEST

Comment: @RamachandranGA I just tried the same thing with Version : Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 however, I am not getting any permission exception. Could you please share the content of your activemq.xml file?

Comment: @RamachandranGA Please note that I am calling the above function as `deleteDestinationQueue("user1","pwd1", "QUEUEB");`